# How to find number of records and update another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table (degrees)like this :

```
dID        dmID    dlID    d11  

540        1         1      44                  
541        1         2      55                  
542        1         3      66                              
545        2         1      56                  
546        2         2      76                  
547        2         3      87                                  
550        3         1      55                  
551        3         2      78                  
552        3         3      87                                  
555        4         1      22                  
556        4         2      22                  
557        4         3      78
```

I want to find how many d11<50 for every dmID
SO I use:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*)  FROM degrees  
 WHERE degrees.[d11]<50
  GROUP BY degrees.dmID
```

This the results:

```
COUNT(*)

   1
   2
```

My Question: How Can I update These values to another table column  called midTable.Result where `midTable.[mid] = degrees.[dmID]` ?

This is midTable Structure:

```
mID    Result

1        null
2        null
3        null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
update midTable
    set Results = (select count(*)
                   from degrees d
                   where d.dmid = midTable.mid and d.d11 < 50
                  );
```

Note:  this will set non-matching values to `0`, which is presumably the intention of the query.